# WiFi keep disconnecting after some time (wireless adapter or access point)

Tags: usb, internet, internet-connection, wifi-configuration

I already unchecked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device" option and also disabled USB selective suspend and, in Advanced Power Settings, "Wireless Adapter Settings" is set to "Maximum Performance".

Still having the issue, I tried using troubleshooter and it worked (troubleshooter reset WiFi) but after some time or after restarting the PC it happens again. It happens randomly. For example, for one week it works perfectly but now it happens daily.

**this is what troubleshooter shows:**

[image: IMAGE OF MESSAGE]

Comment: Generally when this has happened to me, it is a hardware or driver issue. On my main laptop, full uninstall, restart, and install newest wireless driver fixed the issue. On my retired laptop, the issue is wireless card seat or motherboard.  I use Ethernet on this machine. Check also wireless router firmware.

Comment: Please post the detailed information, by clicking on `View detailed information`, so we can see what it has fixed!!!